# Alsa: snd-aloop is creating surround sound devices

Tags: audio, alsa

I need to create two ALSA loopback interfaces to link two applications.

I have the following in /etc/modprobe.d/sound.conf -

```
alias snd-card-1 snd-aloop
options snd-aloop pcm_substreams=2,2 id=1,2 enable=1,1 index=10,11
```

This creates the loopbacks and it's working, but it also creates loads of surround sound interfaces that I do not require. Example below-

```
surround51:CARD=D2,DEV=0
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=D2,DEV=0
    Loopback, Loopback PCM
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
```

Is there anyway I can create loopback devices for Stereo only?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I discovered there were configuration files in:

```
/usr/share/alsa/pcm
```

That were creating the surround sound interfaces. I deleted the files, and the interfaces are no longer created.

Comment: Note that those are the standard configuration files that manage creation of an "additional" layer in ALSA on top of the hardware interfaces. And that means *all* interfaces, not only the loopback one. And even if *you* don't need them, some applications may, and keeping them does no harm. Also, I consider `snd-aloop` one of the most painful ways to get a loopback function, and I'd use it only if it's an ALSA-only system (which most systems today are not).

Comment: I'm open to other suggestions and indeed got it working with pulseaudio, but one of the applications I am linking only supports ALSA.

Comment: It's fairly easy with Pulseaudio (just attach the recording application to the `monitor` source of the sink of the playback application). In principle, **all** ALSA applications should be able to use Pulseaudio via the `pulse` audio device, which you should configure as default ALSA device. Anything particular about your application so it doesn't work this way?

Comment: It may well work, but I've found it hard work to find good documentation on doing it. I need two separate loops if that's worth noting. I have experience using Linux, but having to mess around with sound is new to me

Answer (score 0):

Alternative with Pulseaudio:

To make one application under Pulseaudio record the output of another application is fairly easy:

Pulseaudio has the concept of sound sources and sound sinks. You can arbitrarily connect up application to those. Pulseaudio has modules to remember those connections, and will restore the connection sthe next time the application is restarted (if the connection is possible). Otherwise Pulseaudio will choose default connections for you.

You can inspect and change all this using the `pavucontrol` GUI, which also allows you to change volume controls both on the connection between application and source/sink, and the source/sink itself.

The basic use case four source/sinks is to represent hardware recording and playback. But it's not limited to that: There are various ways to create other kinds of sources and sinks. In particular, each sink has connected to it a `.monitor` source, which just loopbacks. Actually `pavucontrol` uses those to implement the sound metering display.

So settung up two loops, are even 100 loops, or tee-shaped connections with several applications listening to one application is all really straightforward.

If the GUI is not enough for you, there are also commandline applications `pacmd` and `pactl`, that allow scripting. See `pacmd help` or `pactl help` for details. (I've no idea why there are two of them...). However, their output is not particularly easy to parse, and needs a bit of fiddling with `grep -A` etc.

Pulseaudio includes a compatibility layer to allow all ALSA applications to use Pulseaudio, via the `pulse` ALSA device.
If you have an `.asoundrc` like

```
pcm.!default pulse
ctl.!default pulse
```

then every ALSA application will use Pulseaudio by default (unless you configure it to use a different ALSA device). Some ALSA applications think they need to use `hw:...` (which is bad design), and you've to convice those applications to use `default` instead. A few ALSA applications try to do things that only work on `hw:...`, and these will cause problems, but they are rare.

Bottom line: Routing sound is a lot easier with Pulseaudio (or with Jack) than with ALSA directly.